# Right align y-axis text when text has different number of characters

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels, text-alignment, yaxis

I want to do a plot without y-axis ticks and place the y-axis text as close as possible to the plot.

I am therefore using `axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 2)` within `theme()`, but notice that because the labels range from `0` to `40` the `0` value ends up within the plot while the others labels do not.

A small reproducible example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,40)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 2))
```

[image]

Is it possible to align the `0` to the positions of all the other values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg)) + geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,40)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1, margin = margin(0,-3,0,0))
  )
```

Modify `margin` to get the desired result